# Why the resnet110 I train on CIFAR10 dataset only get 77% test acc

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, resnet

I trained the Resnet110 on CIFAR10 dataset, and I got 100% acc on training, but only 77.85% on test dataset. What is the problem probally be?
Otherwise, I use Pytorch framwork.
Thank U very much!

```
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Train Epoch: 200 [0/50000 (0%)] Loss: 0.000811, Accuracy: 100.00
Train Epoch: 200 [12800/50000 (26%)]    Loss: 0.000335, Accuracy: 100.00
Train Epoch: 200 [25600/50000 (51%)]    Loss: 0.000757, Accuracy: 100.00
Train Epoch: 200 [38400/50000 (77%)]    Loss: 0.000334, Accuracy: 100.00
Epoch time:45.98s
Accuracy of plane : 81 %
Accuracy of   car : 88 %
Accuracy of  bird : 65 %
Accuracy of   cat : 60 %
Accuracy of  deer : 73 %
Accuracy of   dog : 69 %    
Accuracy of  frog : 81 %
Accuracy of horse : 82 %
Accuracy of  ship : 86 %
Accuracy of truck : 86 %

Test set: Average loss: 1.3605, Accuracy: 77.58%
```

Comment: You have likely [`overfit`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) the training set. Basically your ResNet has memorized the training set, but its performance on out of sample data (eg. your test set) has been getting worse. Typically this is why people would use a validation set during training to try to monitor out-of-sample performance and stop training before overfitting occurs.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It probally because the over-fitting problem. I will test new hyper-parameters.@JoshVarty

Answer (score 2):

`ResNet-101` is definitely too big for CIFAR10, go with smaller versions, [`ResNet-18`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/models.html#torchvision.models.resnet18) from `torchvision` should be fine.

Furthermore, you could train those really fast using **super convergence** (e.g. setting learning rate to `5` or `3`), see [this article](https://www.fast.ai/2018/07/02/adam-weight-decay/) or other related. You could do so in 18 epochs or so with [`torch.optim.AdamW`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#torch.optim.AdamW) I think. Furthermore, such high learning rate plays a regularizing role as it will only converge to really flat minima regions.

In order to not overfit, use really powerful image augmentation, rotations, flipping, CutOut, maybe MixUp. You could find them inside [`albumentations`](https://github.com/albumentations-team/albumentations) third party library.

Comment: I think he used [resnet custom models for cifar10](https://github.com/akamaster/pytorch_resnet_cifar10). Your augmentation is very smart.

Comment: Oh, yeah, thanks for pointing that out, it probably is the case, if so you can ignore the beginning of my post regarding too big `ResNet`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I just added some data augmentation method, modified the learning-rate and weight_decay rate. The result is 93% now. I guess the most important factors are learning-rate and weight_decay rate.

Answer (score 1):

You are overfitting this is evident. The best possible way to get rid of overfitting is to train on more data.

For this purpose you may do data augmentation using this [repo](https://github.com/aleju/imgaug).

You use special resnet architecture for cifar10 that can get you up to 93% accuracy. This accuracy h/b achieved using data augmentation.

Other techniques to regularize neural network (to reduce overfitting) are:

- Dropout
- Early Stopping

Here is how I can alter resnet18 do add dropout:

```
from torchvision.models import resnet18
model = resnet18(pretrained=True)
model.fc = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Dropout(0.5),
    nn.Linear(512, 10)
)
model.to(dev)
```

Note adding dropout on befor convolution layers is almost never used.

Also check [this URL](https://paperswithcode.com/sota/image-classification-on-cifar-10).
As you may see, no one did 100.00 accuracy on cifar10. :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am afraid that the memory of my GPU can't support so bigger batch size. LOL. I think the main reson is that I didn't set a right initial learning-rate and weight_decay rate.

Comment: Yes, I just want to proof 6.43% error rate or reasonable error rate frankly. Thanks!